# Cant understand the format of django.VERSION :-/

Tags: django

What does this mean?  1.0 or 1.1 ?

> ```
> >>> django.VERSION  
> (1, 1, 1, 'final', 0)
> ```

Apologies for such a dumb question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is a tuple with the following fields:

"major"
    The major version number of the Django release, e.g., 1 for the
    1.x releases.

"minor"
    The minor version number of the Django release, e.g., 0 for the
    1.0.x releases, 1 for the 1.1.x release, etc.

"micro"
    The micro version number of the Django release, e.g., 1 for a
    release number 1.0.1, 2 for a release number 1.0.2, etc.

"release level"
    A short string describing the type of release. Value will be one
    of: "alpha", "beta", "rc" (for release candidates, "final".

"serial"
    For situations where we do more than one release of a given level,
    the incremental number of the release (e.g., 1 for "alpha 1", 3
    for "beta 3", etc.).